Using ethanol as a solvent of sodium hydroxide?
NaOH dissolves in water thanks to solvation. Is it possible to dissolve it in ethanol, which still has polar O-H bond, allowing analogous solvation?

Yes.$\mathstrut$

Ethanol is also a "regular" solvent. In general, the more polar solvent, the more salt-like stuff you can dissolve. Ex. methanol could dissolve more, n-propanol less.

Ethanol can indeed dissolve sodium hydroxide, although not as effectively as water.
Chemists often use potassium hydroxide as a hydroxide base in ethanol solvent. Ethanol has a lower dielectric constant than water and thus salts with compact ions tend to form ion pairs in ethanol. Potassium hydroxide, with a larger, more diffuse cation, is more efficient at providing fully dissociated hydroxide ions for reaction as a strong base.

Ethanol dissolves $\ce{NaOH}$, at least up to concentrations equal to $10$ grams $\ce{NaOH}$ per litre. At higher concentrations, the following equilibrium starts to become important : $$\ce{NaOH + C2H5OH <=> C2H5ONa + H2O}$$

There is a dynamic ionic reaction between EtOH and OH- at low [OH- and low [H2O] the equilibrium will lie on the ethoxide side not the hydroxide side. as OH- and H2O increase  they become more prevalent. The solubility of NaOH is nebulous in dry ethanol since it is not possible. possibly one should consider ethoxide.
